# Google Maps and US Zip Codes

Tags: google-maps, search, zipcode

I need to generate a link that opens up Google Maps and identifies an area based on a US Zip Code in the query string, preferably like below:

[image]

I tried to do it using this query string: https://maps.google.com/?q=us+90120

Appending the zip code at the end. But it doesn't always work. Right now, it's pointing to somewhere near Greenville. What's weird is that if you open up Google Maps and search "us 90210", it does point you to Beverly Hills.

Anything I should add to the query string? Or is the approach all wrong? I just need it to be simple. Any piece of information would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a typo- the link goes to 90120, and therefore, Greenville, but you want to go to 90210, which is Beverly Hills.

Comment: Wow, thanks for that. I feel very stupid now, haha. Leaving this question for anyone who might need it. Thanks for spotting it @Wilson!